# lightning-record-form in an aura parent component. How to add this to a related list page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, related-list

I'm not even sure this is possible from what I have been reading. When you visit a Quote record page and then select the "Quote Lines" link you are brought to a single page with nothing but a list of the Quote Lines for the given quote. I think this is referred to a "Related List" page (but it isn't embedded within the Quote details page itself, it's a stand-alone page). I would like to add a button to this page (at the top, not at the line level). I have the lightning-web-component wrapped in a parent aura component and it works fine as a button on the Quote page itself but the users would like to see this as a button on the Quote Lines list page. Is this even possible? My reading suggests it is possible but I may need to wrap the aura parent in a VisualForce page? Yikes..

Comment: Would you please add a screen shot of the button you would like to overwrite.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do by creating a CPQ Custom Action.. However, I had to wrap my aura component in a parent visualforce page and then set the custom action's URL to that custom page (with an added parameter id={!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}... so: /apex/c__myParentVisualForcePage?id={!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}